# Binary file attachment "unrecognizable format" for postresql and rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, nginx, centos

I currently have a problem with storing files as binary blobs on postresql (9.3) with ruby on rails (4.1.1). When opening the file from staging/production server that I have saved, I get

```
unrecognizable format
```

which means the file is (probably) corrupt. I confirmed that with textedit, where the file downloaded from production displays "x89504e470d0a1a0a0000000d494844520000010b000001c00800000000901112f9000000097048597300000c4e00000c4e017f778c23000003186943435050686f746f736..." (first I thought it was base64 encoded) when it should display the normal PNG header of the testfile "...PNG... IHDR..."

Strangely enough, the problem only happens in production environment (Centos6 + Passenger + NginX) while the development environment (MacOS) works fine. Moreover, I do not know whether this is a Postgres problem, since after I try restoring the production dump on my development machine, the files I uploaded in production opened just fine locally! Here is the code that creates the data_file object (the one with the binary contents in question):

```
def create
  authorize! :create, :data_file # cancan authorization
  file = params[:file]
  @data_file = DataFile.new(name: file.original_filename,
                            size: file.size,
                            contents: file.read,
                            content_type: file.content_type # + some additional params)
  authorize! :update, @data_file # other cancan authorization
  if @data_file.save
    render("data_files/show", formats: :json)
  else
    render json: {errors: @data_file.errors}, status: 403
  end
end
```

and here is the code that displays the file

```
def show
  @data_file = DataFile.find(params[:id])
  authorize! :show, @data_file
  send_data @data_file.contents, :disposition => 'attachment', :filename => @data_file.name
end
```

here is the schema of the datafile object

```
create_table "data_files", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.integer  "project_id"

  t.string   "size"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
  t.binary   "contents"
  t.integer  "content_type"
  t.string   "valid_from"
  t.string   "valid_until"
  t.datetime "formatted_valid_until"
  t.datetime "formatted_valid_from"
end
```

It would be great if someone could help me with that issue. It is strange that a program behaves differently on environments that appear to be the same.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result you're looking at is an hexadecimal string of a value of type `bytea` generated by PostgreSQL 9.0 or higher, which happens when the `bytea_output` parameter is set to `hex`.

A SQL application linked with a pre-9.0 `libpq` won't decode properly these contents and basically regurgitate the hex string verbatim like shown in the question. Presumably the difference between your production and dev environments is the version of `libpq`.

As a workaround, until upgrading, you may force `bytea_ouput` to its older default value, `escape`, at several possible levels, at your convenience:

- for the entire cluster, configured in `postgresql.conf`
- for one database with `ALTER DATABASE dbname SET bytea_output to 'escape';`
- for a specific user: `ALTER USER username SET bytea_output to 'escape';`
- for the SQL session (non-persistent): `SET bytea_output TO 'escape';`

Comment: Thank you, I did `ALTER USER username SET bytea_output to 'escape';` and it worked fine for me.

I still don't think this is a permanent solution, and will try to upgrade my postgres to 9.3.1, which is exactly what I use on my local machnine.